# Update changes from Developement instance to Production instance in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have 2 instances of Odoo v9 running in the same server (Ubuntu 14.04). I want to make changes (install modules, change source code or anything) in the developement instance and after confirming they are OK, move the changes to the Production Instance. Is there anyway of doing that without repeating the whole process of development?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand you do not want to stop the production instance.

If they are only XML files you might be able to get away by only updating the module from the frontend (Apps-> Your Module -> Update. Although if you have modified the `__openerp__.py` file inside your module you have to enter the debug mode and click `Update Apps List` first of all.

For changes in files that are inside the `static` folder of your module, you do not need to stop the server. Although, your users must click `ctr + shift + R` in order to flush their caches and bring to their browsers the new content.

For Python source code I am afraid that you have to stop both instances of the server so that the code can be correctly recompiled.
(See note 1 on this)

In the end you should stop and update everything because unexpected things might pop up at random times due to resources not been properly updated.

**Note 1:** The Python documentation about the compilation of Python modules above others mentions:

> As an important speed-up of the start-up time for short programs that
>   use a lot of standard modules, **if a file called spam.pyc exists in the
>   directory where spam.py is found, this is assumed to contain an
>   already-“byte-compiled” version of the module spam. The modification
>   time of the version of spam.py used to create spam.pyc is recorded in
>   spam.pyc, and the .pyc file is ignored if these don’t match**.

So theoretically if you modify fileA.py in a module and a new fileA.pyc is generated the server will be able to interpret and use it. In any case I had an issue with two instances running where the py file was creating the field and the XML file was using it and the server reported that a filed had not been created for the XML view, that means that the server did pick up and parse the XML file but did not recompile the py.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was what I was looknig for.